# Plotting color graph setting array element with a sequence

Tags: arrays, plot, sequence, element

I'm trying to produce a colored graph using the below code

```
x = range(0,170)
y = range(0,60)
X,Y = meshgrid(x, y) # grid of point
Z = ATFS.ATFS(state, T, dt, Y, tm, td, sigma, D, X, f, A, measurement)
```

Where ATFS uses **X** in a matrix. This produces the error

> arr = N.array(data, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
>
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I know if I use `Z = X*Y` it works and it doesn't matter that they are a sequence so what wrong here?